# .htaccess 301 rewrites with question marks

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm using something similar to the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

Redirect 301 / http://newdomain.co.uk/link/
Redirect 301 /showcase.asp?showcaseid=1 http://newdomain.co.uk/track1
Redirect 301 /showcase.asp?showcaseid=2 http://newdomain.co.uk/track2
Redirect 301 /showcase.asp?showcaseid=3 http://newdomain.co.uk/track3
Redirect 301 /showcase http://newdomain.co.uk/link/tracks
```

With that in mind any URL other than the mentione would go to http://newdomain.co.uk/link

Which is fine however any of the other URL's that use a "?" go to say http://newdomain.co.uk/link/showcaseid=1 for /showcase.asp?showcaseid=1

Also with the

```
Redirect 301 /showcase http://newdomain.co.uk/link/tracks
```

can I just write as follows:

```
Redirect 301 /showcase tracks
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't match against the query string (everything after the `?`) in a `Redirect` directive. You have to use mod_rewrite's `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^showcaseid=([0-9])
RewriteRule ^showcase\.asp$ http://newdomain.co.uk/track%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^showcase$ http://newdomain.co.uk/link/tracks [L,R=301]
RewriteRUle ^$ http://newdomain.co.uk/link/ [L,R=301]
```

Note that the order is important. You generally want the more general matching rules to be at the end.